# Fetch more than 2000 records

Tags: soql, tooling-api, governorlimits

I want to fetch 19k records from my org using Tooling API in Java. I have used `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` values in SOQL query to maintain sequence, the problem I'm facing is `OFFSET` is not processing values more than 2000.

In first run `LIMIT=2000 and OFFSET=0`, and in the 2nd run it will be `LIMIT=2000 and OFFSET=2001`.

The error I got is:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400`

Comment: From the error code in your question, it doesn't look like your error is related to the problem you describe. A [400 HTTP Error Code is a "Bad Request"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). You will likely need to debug this on your end, and [edit] your question to provide relevant information to the error code.

Comment: Already i have debugged and tested with multiple values of OFFSET.  JAVA code is working till OFFSET=2000 after that it is throwing error. With POSTMAN Tool it is showing following error:
[{"message":"Maximum SOQL offset allowed is 2000","errorCode":"NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE"}] 
@battery.cord

Comment: Thats a much more useful error, it shows that there isnt a syntax error causing your error to be rejected. It looks like you won't be able to pull all 19k rows via `OFFSET`, if you checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm), the max value for `OFFSET` is 2k. Have you tried using other methods, such as [`queryMore`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#topic-title)?

Comment: @battery.cord Can you post the usage of `queryMore` as an answer. It is probably the best option for paging through multiple records from the Tooling API.

Comment: Thanks @battery.cord the queryMore method worked for me.

Comment: If an answer helped you, consider [accepting that answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `OFFSET` is limited to a total of 2,000 records, [`query`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm#topic-title) & [`queryMore`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#topic-title) can be configured to return 2,000 records each call.

To do this, you need to first [set the batch size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm) for your connection via:

> `connection.setQueryOptions(2000);`

Then, you need to call `query`, and return the first 2,000 records. The return value of `query` is a [`QueryResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_queryresult.htm#topic-title), which contains the results, as well as a [`QueryLocator`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_querylocator.htm#topic-title). The `QueryLocator` can be provided to the `queryMore` call to essentially perform an identical function as `OFFSET`, but supports a much higher number of records.

> `QueryResult = connection.queryMore(QueryLocator someQueryLocator);`

From here, you repeat calls to `queryMore`, using the `QueryLocator` returned in the `QueryResult` from each call. Once the value of `QueryResult.done` is equal to true, you've retrieved all of the results from Salesforce, and can continue doing whatever your java app was doing.

---

I've included the example code from [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#topic-title) below, which uses `query`, and `queryMore` to fetch a large number of records from the database.

> ```
> public void queryRecords() {
>    QueryResult qResult = null;
>    try {
>       String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact";
>       qResult = connection.query(soqlQuery);
>       boolean done = false;
>       if (qResult.getSize() > 0) {
>          System.out.println("Logged-in user can see a total of "
>             + qResult.getSize() + " contact records.");
>          while (!done) {
>             SObject[] records = qResult.getRecords();
>             for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
>                Contact con = (Contact) records[i];
>                String fName = con.getFirstName();
>                String lName = con.getLastName();
>                if (fName == null) {
>                   System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + lName);
>                } else {
>                   System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + fName
>                         + " " + lName);
>                }
>             }
>             if (qResult.isDone()) {
>                done = true;
>             } else {
>                qResult = connection.queryMore(qResult.getQueryLocator());
>             }
>          }
>       } else {
>          System.out.println("No records found.");
>       }
>       System.out.println("\nQuery successfully executed.");
>    } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
>       ce.printStackTrace();
>    }
> }
> ```